# CWNAN0020W Socket error on socket 4, peer address <IP Address>:57710; ending connection

Tags: android, notifications, push, mqtt, broker

I have installed php SAM library for Really Small message broker (RSMB MQTT). And I'm trying to connect Android Push Demo, but it getting following error

> [root@user linux_ia64]# tail -f nohup.out
>   20120501 120111.226 CWNAN9997I Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
>   20120501 120111.226 CWNAN9996I Copyright IBM Corp. 2007, 2010 All Rights Reserved
>   20120501 120111.226 CWNAN9995I US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
>   20120501 120111.226 CWNAN0053I Version 1.2.0, Aug 18 2010 17:02:09
>   20120501 120111.226 CWNAN0054I Features included: bridge
>   20120501 120111.226 CWNAN9993I Author: Ian Craggs (icraggs@uk.ibm.com)
>   20120501 120111.226 CWNAN0014I MQTT protocol starting, listening on port 1883
>
> **20120501 120126.609 CWNAN0020W Socket error on socket 4, peer address ipaddress:34861; ending connection**

Pls anyone help to fix the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running the PHP server? is it possible that you have an issue with the connection between that and the MQTT broker?

The SAM PHP library is quite old and not currently maintained, so you might want to look at one of the other PHP MQTT options like phpMQTT instead.

Comment: Thanks Andypiper. I'm running the PHP in Centos 6.2 Server. Could you please explain me in detail.

Comment: there's another PHP MQTT implementation called phpMQTT - see the Software page on mqtt.org. It might be better than SAM.